# Adding a variable to a group of array

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using angular js to produce to add an array and display it as we go along. So far the given code adds an array to the list but it doesn't keep adding the array with the press of the function.

I'm quite new to angular and i think there's something I'm missing but right now I'm stuck.

The html code has a button linked which is supposed to carry out the function.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.records = ["Testing Task 5.1", "Downloaded Task 5.1"];

  $scope.addArray = function() {
    $scope.records.unshift("saddfadffas")
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  <p>
    <h3>Status: </h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="additem">
    <button ng-click="addArray()">function</button>
  </p>

  <ul ng-repeat="x in records">
    <li>{{x}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: does an error message appear in your console? this looks like it should work.

Comment: it does seem to work fine actually: http://jsfiddle.net/q06dh1qv/1/

Comment: mine adds in one and stops after that

Comment: The whole page displays one saddfadffas on the existing list of array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by having the items in your array be keyed by their position rather than their value. To do this, you can use `track by $index`. Hope this helps!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.records = ["Testing Task 5.1", "Downloaded Task 5.1"];

  $scope.addArray = function() {
    $scope.records.unshift("saddfadffas")
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  <p>
    <h3>Status: </h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="additem">
    <button ng-click="addArray()">function</button>
  </p>

  <ul ng-repeat="x in records track by $index">
    <li>{{x}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `push` rather than`unshift`? Sorry I am not at my computer right now so can't verify this, but I'm pretty sure this will solve the problem

Comment: hey dacre, 
i've already tried push, both unshift and push add in one variable but stop after that. I want it to keep adding variables with the press of the button

Comment: Have you confirmed that the addarray method is being called?

Comment: yes the addarray is being called. I've tried an alert in the function and it seems to be working however the variable is only being added once.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Perhaps your intention is

```
$scope.records.unshift($scope.additem)
```

rather than

```
$scope.records.unshift("saddfadffas")
```

but I am assuming you are perhaps running into an error we can't see from the excerpt you posted.

Comment: Hey mikey,

Its producing the same result.